# Can I specify using SSD space for an EC2 instance using awscli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have the following command being run in a script to launch an ec2 instance.

```
aws ec2 run-instances --instance-initiated-shutdown-behavior terminate --instance-type c3.4xlarge --image-id ami-7172b611 --count 1 --key-name [removed] --security-groups [removed] --region us-west-2
```

The problem I've found is the SSD doesn't mount (I know this has been a problem for about a million years.) I know I can use ssh to send commands to solve this, but can I specify space using my `run-instances` command?

I still don't fully understand why the SSD is not allocated by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `--block-device-mappings` with the value of a local file containing JSON describing the disk or use the shorthand string format.

It's described in the documentation although the information regarding the parameter is fairly spread out on the page: [run-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html)

Example configuration describing a 100 GB General Purpose SSD (gp2 is General Purpose SSD):

```
[
  {
    "DeviceName": "/dev/sdh",
    "Ebs": {
      "VolumeSize": 100,
      "VolumeType"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Ok, so will that be mounted to the home directory? Or will I need to modify all my scripts to change their paths?

Comment: @DylanLawrence to modify to root disk I think you should just set the `DeviceName` to `/dev/sda1`, however I'm not entirely sure. Worth testing!